# Get client IP in shared hosting web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` to get client machine name and IP. But it giving me server machine name and IP.

Also, is there any steps to get client local machine `IP` (Not proxy IP) through JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: You would have got of solutions for the same like **[this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-IP-Address-of-Visitors-Machine-in-ASP.Net.aspx)** here..

Comment: You may also install ARRHelper (http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr) for IIS which replaces the IP address of the proxy by the IP address of the client for you.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: thanks for your quick reply, I m specifically talking about C# coding

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Much appreciated for your quick reply, i tried your solution. but problem here is every time i get something like "::1" as Ip . but sometime it will return correct Ip

Comment: You can check this service provider name **[IPInfoDB](http://www.ipinfodb.com/)**. You will have lot of options.. Also **[check this tutorial on that](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Latitude-and-Longitude-using-IP-Address-in-ASPNet.aspx)**